# Matching range with several validation values with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have one sheet `(Sheet1)` with three columns I want to copy to Sheet2.

The cell `WB1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J5")` has multiple validation that uses   the range `WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Lastrow)`. The user can select one or more values from this range. If multiple, the validation concatenates them: "`one, two, three`"

I need to match the validation cell with its multiple values to the range `WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Lastrow)` and copy the corresponding values in  `WB1.Sheets("Sheet1")` to `WB1.Sheets("Sheet2")`

My problem is that this code only works if there is one entry in `Range("J5")` that contains the validation.

```
Sub test()

Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim I As Long


Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook


WB1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B6:H100" & LastRow).Clear

LastRow = WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row




For I = 6 To LastRow
    If WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & I).Value = WB1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J5").Value Then
        WB1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & I, "F" & I).Value = WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & I, "F" & I).Value
        WB1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & I).Value = WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J5").Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Check InStr function maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by **I have validation that includes multiple values (and concatenates them) from `WB1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Lastrow)`**. Especially, "and concatenates them"... Do you mean that the cell in discussion list validation uses that range as source? If so, please clarify the "concatenation" meaning. If not, please better explain what kind of list does the validation uses.

Comment: Sure, as this is the source of my problem...I hope now the question is a bit more clear.